# Search plugin of Folium doesn't appear

Tags: geojson, geopandas, python-3, folium

I'm trying to reproduce the following jupyter notebook :

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jtbaker/folium/blob/geojsonmarker/examples/plugin-Search.ipynb

But once I'm trying to create the map I had to make a few changes to the search plugin because of the documentation:

```
citysearch = Search(layer=citygeo, 
                geom_type='Point', 
                placeholder="Search for a US City", 
                collapsed=True, 
                search_label='nameascii'
               ).add_to(m)
```

becomes, according to the folium documentation [here](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html#folium.plugins.Search) :

```
citysearch = Search(data=citygeo, 
                   geom_type='Point', 
                   search_label='nameascii'
                   ).add_to(m)
```

The issue is that, at best the search plugin doesn't appear and at worse my folium map isn't displayed. Does anyone have this problem as well ? Or is there any dependecies I've forgot ?

Comment: what does the browser console say?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` on this line : 
`var macro_element_6d25be1d6f0b4126bc445bdd631cf103 = new L.GeoJSON(<folium.features.GeoJson object at 0x00000000886896D8>);`

Comment: That hints at a lack of JavaScript understanding, I recommend you either learn some of that or go to the general programming https://stackoverflow.com/ for help on programming.

Comment: The problem I'm asking is about the Python code which is supposed to generate the javascript code through the folium library, not the javascript code itself

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot. :) Then this *might* hint at a Folium bug. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that exhibits the problem so we can help.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'll create a new question with a minimal example to put the problem clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright found the solution after couple days of research,

The example in the notebook is using a new `search.py`file which isn't updated in the folium document yet (as the working version is from december 23 2018 so it's very recent)

I just went to the `plugin`folder to change the `search.py` with the github newest version [Here](https://github.com/jtbaker/folium/blob/SearchRefactor/folium/plugins/search.py)
Then it doesn't update automatically to my notebooks so I just created a new one and there it works !

Comment: Sweet! I was just going to notify you about the brand-new folium 0.8 release that *just* happened, as the search plugin is mentioned in its docs. I'll notify the author, so they fix their examples. Don't forget to mark your answer as solution!

Comment: Yes I saw it today, now it works perfectly ! Thank you again, today I can't mark solution yet (blocked by stackExchange), I will put a mark tomorrow